# Maths with Ternary Boolean in Python

Tags: python, conditional-operator, boolean-logic

I wrote this little script to calculate dog years. The first two dog years are 10.5 human years and all other years following are worth 4.

```
human_age = int(input("Enter the human age to convert it to doggy years: "))
    valid = (human_age <=2)
    def convert_to_dog_years(human_age):
        if valid:
            dog_years = human_age * 10.5
            print('Dog age is:', int(dog_years))
        elif not valid:
            dog_years = ((((human_age - 2) * 4) + 21))
            print('Dog age is:', int(dog_years))
    convert_to_dog_years(human_age)
```

I was thinking something more along those lines:
I would like to specify the mathematical operations giving them two names one for numbers from 0-2 and the other from 2 and up.
Then I would like to use a boolean to decide which math process I want to apply.

Is this possible in python?

```
0-2    = dog_years = human_age * 10.5
>=2    = dog_years = ((((human_age - 2) * 4) + 21))

human_age = int(input("Enter the human age to convert it to doggy years: "))
valid = (human_age <=2)
def convert_to_dog_years(human_age):
    if valid 0-2 else 2&up
        print('Dog age is:', int(dog_years))
convert_to_dog_years(human_age)
```

Comment: edit to have `human_age` as one line: `human_age = int(input(....)`, why `0-2` is there a better variable choice? what's the issue with first choice, both cases do make use of boolean anyways with the help of `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While, the question is not clearly articulated, It seems you are looking at ways to store functions and call these conditionally.

> Good news is that, in python functions are first class object.

So you could do something like this -

```
>>> handlers={
...  'valid':lambda human_age:human_age * 10.5,
...  'invalid': lambda human_age:((((human_age - 2) * 4) + 21))}
>>> handler_key = 'valid' if human_age <=2 else 'invalid'
>>> human_age=3 #In your case, take input here
>>> print(handlers[handler_key](human_age)) #call handler
25
```

To further respond to OPs comment, lambda's are not essential here by any means. Following is the same code with simple functions -

```
>>> def invalid_handler(human_age): return ((((human_age - 2) * 4) + 21))
... 
>>> def valid_handler(human_age): return human_age * 10.5
... 
>>> handlers = {
...  'valid': valid_handler,
...  'invalid': invalid_handler}
>>> 
>>> print(handlers[handler_key](human_age))
25
>>> human_age=1
>>> print(handlers[handler_key](human_age))
17
```

I would also take this opportunity for a short rant against python and almost all modern programming languages in general -

> In modern programming languages, Why are there so many ways to do the same thing?

Python Zen, no. 13, states -

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Yet, there are multiple ways to achieve the same results. I really wish modern programming languages kill the temptation to add as many features as possible and instead focus on doing the most important job better - Speed, tooling, better versioning, frameworks.

*I come from 'C' background and I believe it is the best programming language created till date.*

Comment: Im sorry for asking such a dumb question, but why are you using lambda? Thanks in advance

Comment: @dev, it's not essential, just helps to shorten the code in this case. I'll update the code to work without lambda as well.

Comment: Really appreciate your comments on style. Would you mind telling me if for this particular mini script am I better off using the if else with booleans as per my original program at the very top. When would it be good practise to use your lambda version?

Comment: Almost always better of not using lambdas. I rarely use those in production code myself. Remember - Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.

Answer (score -1):

I think it’s enough to use

```
age = input("How old are you? ").val
print "That's " + age*7 + " in dog years."
```

Comment: Might be a different language though

Comment: That doesn't even compile. And misses half the problem.